# How to get data from mongodb after saving it using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

My web application is like quiz app, the user should answer a question and the server will store the user's result in mongoDB database.
what I is want is after saving the document in the database I want to get this document to send it to user in the browser
**note saving documents works fine**.
code looks like this (assuming the user's result is 10):

```
    const User_Result = require("../models/result_model")
```

```
router.post("/quiz/results", (req, res)=>{
       var result = new User_Result({
            _id: req.user._id,
            userResult: 10
      })
      result.save()


     //that should get data and send it but it send empty []
     User_Result.find({_id: req.user._id}).then(data=>{
            res.send(data)
        })
})
```

I think the problem that it looks for the data before saving it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `find` as `.save()` will return the saved document you can just use it

Async/Await version

```
router.post("/quiz/results", async (req, res)=>{
       let result = new User_Result({
            _id: req.user._id,
            userResult: 10
      })
       const ReturnedResult = await result.save();
       return res.status(201).json(ReturnedResult);
})
```

Promise Version

```
router.post("/quiz/results",  (req, res) => {
    let result = new User_Result({
      _id: req.user._id,
      userResult: 10
    })
    result.save()
      .then(ReturnedResult =>return res.status(201).json(ReturnedResult))
      .catch(err => return res.status(500).json(err))

  })
```

Comment: your answers are very helpful but now I update the question, so can you help?

Answer (score 1):

result.save() returns a promise, you should wait for it to be resolved:

```
result.save().then(() => {
  User_Result.find({_id: req.user._id}).then(data=>{
    res.send(data)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
router.post("/quiz/results", async (req, res)=>{
       var result = new User_Result({
            _id: req.user._id,
            userResult: 10
      })
      const newResult = await result.save():
       return res.send(newResult).status(201);
})
```